# Steam family share resets itself randomly

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

So my younger brother family shares with me, and sometimes his library stops showing up. Usually I can just click play on his game, and a 'request access' menu pops up, and upon clicking that I instantly get verified. Today however, the same thing happened, except no window shows up to verify. The game just straight up does not open. If I go to the actual game executable for any of the games, it launches just fine (normally this would also trigger the 'request access' message box). It doesn't show me in game on steam through this method, and the steam overlay doesn't work.

Comment: What game? Some you cannot share.

Comment: Binding of Isaac, Broforce, Mutiple lego games, witcher 3, along wiht a lot more. I know for a fact they are shareable because of the fact that I used them before and don't appear on the list that family share provides my brother that cannot funtion through shared.

Comment: I have this issue lots, so I'm presuming it's an issue with steam. Usually restarting it fixes the issue where it doesn't always grant access.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change at all with restarting steam or my PC.

Comment: Make sure your bother is not playing any game when you try to play one of his games. Family sharing means that if you're playing on of his games and he starts playing a game, you have five minutes to save and quit before Steam will force-quit you from your game. Normally a dialog box should appear when trying to play a game while the family member is playing, but sometimes Steam "misses" bringing the dialog box up.

Comment: I can guarantee it's not that, he hasn't been able to get on for 2 months, and the logo would change from 'play' to 'purchase'.

Comment: This sounds like a question for Steam Support. This is certainly a bug, and I would be amazed if anyone here has the solution

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue sharing libraries with my roommate. Occasionally it will forget that one of our computers is authorized on the other's account, the only workaround I've found is to log in on the other account and reset it. I've had to do this around a dozen times in the last few years, I haven't found a more convenient solution but it does reliably fix the issue.